# Insert New Record in 2 connected table by using binding source(linq to sql)

Tags: sql, linq, join, bindingsource

I have a project with 2 tables, one with 3 fields and another with 15 fields.  Both tables have a common key **EMP_NO** and this field is primary key in both tables.

How can I insert new records into these tables?
I am using a **Datagridview** for table one and a **textbox** for fields of table 2, in master/Detail style.

Comment: Please post your efforts and error you got .

Comment: Do you mean DataGridView? Are you using Windows Forms or ASP.NET?

Comment: Yes Datagridview, i'm using windowsform and VB .net.
actually i tried some differnt approaches none of them was correct.
any suggestion , how could i implement it?